# Is First-Party Cookie also going to be abandoned in the future?

Tags: cookies, third-party-cookies

I see news that Google Chrome will drop support for Third-Party Cookie in 2023 and Safari already did. However, I don’t see any information about how they will deal with First-Party Cookie. Do you think First-Party Cookie will also be abandoned in the future? I think without First-Party Cookie, we would lose UX but I wonder if there’s alternative method.